# tensorflow installation in win10 failed with setup.py error code 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow for many number of times but couldn't get to do it.so I tried removing python completely from my system and made a new installation of anaconda and tried to install tensorflow and again I keep getting the same errors.(tensorflow)

> C:\Users\Siva>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
>   Collecting tensorflow   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/88/417f18ca7eed5ba9bebd51650d04a4af929f96c10a10fbb3302196f8d098/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
>   Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_7fwr2tu\termcolor\

Comment: for which python version are you trying to install the tensorflow?

Comment: In windows, Tensorflow supports for Python 3.5 and above

Comment: yeah I installed 3.6 version

Comment: Possibly dll mismatch. I would say create an environment in anaconda with python3.6 and install Tensorflow 1.7 or 1.8 . I use them and work properly

Comment: Possibly dll mismatch. I would say create an environment in anaconda with python3.6 and install Tensorflow 1.7 or 1.8 . I use them and work properly

Comment: The error that I posted came while I was installing tensorflow by creating an environment in anaconda

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. Its not related to setuptools.

Solution:

1. Download termcolor package from pypi [Link](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/#files). For me, pip install termcolor did not work.
2. Untar and unzip the package. Copy the termcolor.py to your python's site-packages folder. Test if import termcolor works in your python.
3. Install tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks! This helps me in my tensorflow installation!